# Two storyboards, both contain TabBarControllers. How to segue between them?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have two storyboards, and both contain a TabBarController. Let's call the first storyboard/TabBarController **Groups** and the second **Users**

When I segue from **Groups** to **Users**, the **Users** UI appears, but the **Groups** tab bar remains.

How can I segue from **Groups** to **Users** such that the UI ***and*** tabbar changes.

EDIT:

## **My goal**

[image: my goal]

Comment: Just do a presentation / modal segue from one tab bar controller to the other. What's the problem?

Comment: You can also  use page view controller, be a simple swipe can go from groups to users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking to do is perfectly legal and easy. Simple do a present / modal segue from one UITabBarController to the other. This will completely replace the interface (the first tab bar controller and its tab bar) with a new interface (the second tab bar controller and *its* tab bar).

Comment: This is producing the desired effect

Answer (score 1):

Don't use segue for this. It is impossible to let UIKit know what you are really want to do is switching the tab, it just think you want to create a viewController instantiate from storyboard and push it into nav stack.

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = // the index of your dest tab, start from 0
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is against Apple's guideline regarding Tab Bar. That said, I'm sure you can do it if you really wanted to, but I'd suggest you rethink your design because:

1. Design perspective: Apple's HIG is pretty sensibly laid out for a smart phone environment, so following it is more helpful than outright ignoring it.
2. Practical perspective: Your app's chance of getting rejected at App Store will be higher.

From Apple's iOS Human Interface Guideline:

> Use a tab bar to give users access to different perspectives on the
>   same set of data or different subtasks related to the overall function
>   of your app.
>
> In general, use a tab bar to organize information at the app level. A
>   tab bar is well suited for use in the main app view because it’s a
>   good way to flatten your information hierarchy and provide access to
>   several peer information categories or modes at one time.
>
> Don’t use a tab bar to give users controls that act on elements in the
>   current screen or app mode. If you need to provide controls, including
>   a control that displays a modal view, use a toolbar instead (for usage
>   guidelines, see Toolbar).

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52)

Comment: Is not totally correct, what apple says is that you should not call or embed a tab view controller from another tab view controller, but is totally fine present it modally or from another container VC such as a page view controller. There a least 2 apple's application that does this (contact probably)